# Sample of Android View display list commands?

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, displaylist

I would like to know Android View rendering mechanism better and I know that those high level View is represented by a lower level internal object called *display list* which will be transferred to GPU to be renderred.

However, the articles and materials only talk about 'display list is the commands we ask the GPU to render,' no one gives a concrete example for, for example, how a Button is conveted to a display list, and what a display list for a Button looks like.

Can somebody give some examples of display lists for some common Views like Button or TextView?

Comment: There is some explanation of display lists in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#model